# php gets stringified object as null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a some information to a php page with jquery ajax. I really can't understand why the php page keeps echoing back that the strinified JSON i'm sending is null

```
//php
if ($type == "new" || $type == "update"){
    $new_address = json_decode($_REQUEST['address'], true);
    echo json_encode($new_address); //Null
}

//js
var string_encoded_address = JSON.stringify(address_obj.address);
string_encoded_address = encodeURIComponent(string_encoded_address);
console.log(string_encoded_address);
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "order_queries_templates/queries/address.php",
    data: "type=new&user_id=" + user_id + "&address=" + string_encoded_address,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
    }
});
```

this gives me a string for my `data` property:

```
type=new&user_id=8244&address=%7B%22companyName%22%3A%22test%20company%22%2C%22address1%22%3A%222420%20sample%20Road%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22SIOUX%20CITY%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22IA%22%2C%22zip%22%3A%2251106%22%2C%22cityStateZip%22%3A%22SIOUX%20CITY%2C%20IA%2051106%22%7D
```

What could be wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to `urldecode($_REQUEST['address']) ` before you can use it.

Comment: Try stringifying the ENTIRE query you set up and pass as `data`.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt okay tried this...didn't really have any effect. thanks though

Comment: what is `var_dump($_REQUEST['address'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled. It adds escaping to the double quotes, as can be seen using this `cli` script:

```
$s = 'address=%7B%22companyName%22%3A%22test%20company%22%7D';
// parse query string into array
parse_str($s, $a);
// print address portion
echo $a['address'], "\n";

php -dmagic_quotes_gpc=On test.php
```

Output:

```
{\"companyName\":\"test company\"}
```

The additional escaping breaks `json_decode()` so it returns `null`.

Turning `magic_quotes_gpc` off will fix this particular issue, either by using `.htaccess` or editing the `php.ini`.

However, it's far easier to just let jQuery take care of the serialization for you:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    data: {
      type:'new', 
      user_id: user_id, 
      adress: address_obj.address
    },
    ...
});
```

In this case you won't have to `json_decode()` on the server anymore, just reference `$_POST['address']` directly.

Comment: @thomas No problem; do take note of the second part of my answer that discusses an easier way to handle data sending.

Comment: it will just recognize `address_obj.address` as a json object and do that stringification for me and php will understand it as an associative array the same as it would `json_decode($var, **TRUE**)`?

Comment: @thomas Wat? I have no idea what you're talking about, sorry :)

Comment: no, i'm sorry. not very clear. When I pass the second parameter `true` to `json_decode()`, it turns the JSON string into an associative array. I just wondered how I will get an associative array from the JSON when I have removed the `json_decode()` from the server. Like you said in the last two lines of your answer. EDIT:removed a question I now see you've already answered in the last line. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @thomas using the last bit of my answer is similar to what you would achieve with the `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()` :)